# A Href .zip download redirects to Homepage

Tags: html

I zipped a file on the server and created a link using

```
<a href="/Portals/0/3DView.zip" style="line-height: 30px;" class="iconLink">Download 3D View</a>
```

Now whenever the link is clicked I am being redirected to the Homepage. Is it possible that this is not working due to security reasons with the zip file itself since I compressed it on the server?

Comment: What "server" are you using?

Comment: Is this a *direct* link to the file, or is it being delivered via a script?  Do you have an `.htaccess` or anything set?  Did you check if the file exists and has valid permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a security reason which I solved simply by compressing the files on my local machine and than uploaded the .zip file to the server. It seems the server was applying security while compressing.